# Error AngularJs: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Error AngularJs:

I don't understand why I get

> 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined' on this line:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('pessoaCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService', function ($scope, dataService) {
            $scope.pessoas = [];
            getData();

            function getData() {
                //error thrown here
                dataService.getPessoas().then(function (response) {
                    $scope.pessoas = response;
                });
            };
        }]);
})();
```

Comment: could you post the relevant parts of `dataService.getPessoas()`?

Comment: It means that `dataService.getPessoas()` returned a value of `undefined`. This usually happens when a function lacks a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return). New programmers often don't realize that values returned inside anonymous functions don't return those values to parent functions.

Comment: Share `getPessoas()` implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your factory implementation with this

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('dataService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
      return {
        getPessoas: getPessoas
      };
      let getPessoas = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        //return $http.get("/api/EmployeeInfoAPI");
        $http.get('/Pessoas/GetAllPessoas')
        .then(function(result) {
          deferred.resolve(result.data);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          deferred.reject(err);
        });
        return deferred.promisse;
      };
    }]);
})();
```